# Почему for работает, а forEach не работает?

Tags: javascript, foreach, for

У меня есть функция, которая дезактивирует инпуты:

```js
function disableInputsAndSelects() {
  for (var i = 0; i < allInputsAndSelects.length; i++) {
    allInputsAndSelects[i].setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
}
```

И есть функция, которая их активирует:

```js
function activateInputsAndSelects() {
  allInputsAndSelects.forEach(function (el) {
    el.removeAttribute('disabled');
  });
}
```

Но если я пытаюсь переписать функцию дезактивации на forEach, то она не работает:

```js
function disableInputsAndSelects
  allInputsAndSelects.forEach(function (el) {
    el.setAttribute('disabled');
  });
 }
```

Что не так?

[Весь код](https://jsfiddle.net/cheriko/umydtchj/23/)

Answer (score 2):

Потому что атрибут не синхронизируется со свойством. Менять атрибут неправильно, надо менять свойство.

```js
var allInputs = document.querySelectorAll('input')

function disable() {
  allInputs.forEach(function (el) {
    el.disabled = true;
  });
}

function activate() {
  allInputs.forEach(function (el) {
    el.disabled = false;
  });
}

document.getElementById('act').addEventListener('click', activate)
document.getElementById('dis').addEventListener('click', disable)
```

```html
<p><input value=a> <input value=b> <input value=c>

<p><button id=act>activate</button> <button id=dis>disable</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

В таких случаях, первое место, куда надо смотреть, - консоль браузера и ошибки в ней.

```
  allInputsAndSelects.forEach(function (el) {
    el.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
  });
```

Comment: Тогда лучше `el.disabled = true/false;`?

Comment: @Leonid Сейчас не об этом :).

Comment: Да как раз на манер jQuery писать и вызывает ошибки, а так ясно и просто. Имхо.

Answer (score 0):

Дело не в методе forEach.

Метод setAttribute() указывает атрибуты по правилам XHTML. Они предполагают формат атрибут='значение'.

Поэтому вы можете использовать forEach, однако метод setAttribute должен иметь вид **setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled')**

Comment: спасибо вам, поняла

Comment: всегда пожалуйста)